# Can't we know where other Android apps' private db file is?

Tags: android, security, filesystems, sandbox

We can make a private db on Android.
For the private db, other apps can not even see where the db file is.(The db file is not listed)
How Android implemented this? Is it just filesystem feature?

On Linux filesystem(says it is ext4), if we set `chown root:root db-file` and `chmod 700 db-file`, other users can do listing the file. This is what I'm confusing.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question - probably better to be migrated to android.stackexchange.com.

Comment: For the record, it's a perfectly good question, just isn't really phrased as a programming question with programming content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every application (with some minor exceptions) in Android during the installation receives its own UID and GID. Thus, every application in Android is analog of a user in Linux. Linux kernel using sandboxing on a filesystem level prevents one application from accessing to the files of another application (the analog for this is home directory for every user in Linux). Thus, in Linux only the owner of the home directory (and root) has access to this direct and other users cannot.

If you have a root access to Android you can change the modifiers of the file like you propose in the question. So you can make a folder to be accessible from other applications. Moreover, when you create a file you can set that this file is world-readable and in this case all applications will have access to this file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is called as sandboxing. Essentially it use Linux file permission to enforce this.

Let me know in case you need more info.

Comment: added a sentence in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of how databases's work is wrong. Application each have their own database that unless have been linked to a contentprovider are specific to the package that it belongs to.